# Trying to calculate the total amount of sales for each branch since the start of the year

Tags: mysql

I'm currently trying to solve a problem where I'm trying to calculate the total amount of sales for each store branch since the beginning of the year, within the database I've created.

I have tried to write a query that returns the result from one store e.g London, however, there are a few more branch_ids e.g. Manchester, Cardiff etc... At the moment it only returns the London store however I'm stuck on how to also print out the other branch_ids so all branch_ids display the total turnover for each individual store.

```
SELECT branch_id,
       date_sale,
       sum(cost_order)
FROM Customer_Orders
WHERE branch_id like '%London%'
    AND date_sale >='2019-01-01';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use this version:

```
SELECT
    branch_id,
    SUM(cost_order) AS total
FROM Customer_Orders
WHERE date_sale BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-12-31'
GROUP BY
    branch_id;
```

Note that it does not make sense to include the `date_sale` field in your select clause, because each record in the output actually corresponds to *multiple* dates of sale.  Also, I use `BETWEEN` to express the year 2019, because writing it this way is SARGable, meaning that an index on `date_sale` can be used.